# Convert 0-3.3 V of micro DAC output to 0-10 V and protect it

Tags: operational-amplifier, dac

I want to convert the output of DAC channel of STM32 (0-3.3 V) to 0-10 V. As a simple solution I've used an OP07 as a non-inverting amplifier with a gain of 3. I've drawn this schematic and want to know if it would operate well and normally or not?

[image]

- Is it ok to use an SS14 Schottky diode for protecting from output reverse voltages?
- The exact gain is 3.1 , which will lead to about 10.23 V on pin 6, and with a drop of about 0.2 V the output voltage of the connector (DAC_Out) will be 10 V

Please let me know all about you think about this circuit.

Comment: 1. Why do you need this protection? 2. You can close the feedback after the diode (perhaps with some added compensation), and do away with the voltage drop across the diode. 3. OP07 is not single supply. The input must be > 1-2 V from ground.

Comment: thank you for the reply. 
1- It's an extra protection in order to now damage the components if someone apply voltage by mistake.
2- great! thanks. will do that.
3-  oh... would you please let me know what OPamp I should choose ??

Comment: I have done something like this with LM358 dual OpAmp before. would it be a good choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be problems with your op-amp: -

[image]

The input voltage range is guaranteed to be +/-13 volts if the supply is +/-15 volts. This means that with a grounded negative supply pin, the input signal needs to be at least 2 volts before the op-amp is guaranteed to work.

Similar story for the output; it will swing to typically 2 volts of the supply rails meaning that it can't produce output voltages lower than 2 volts.

If you can live with the offset errors, maybe an LM324 op-amp would be a better choice.

> *Is it ok to use an SS14 Schottky diode for protecting from output
> reverse voltages?*

I'm not sure what the threat is here. You can also put the diode inside the op-amp feedback loop and then you don't need to try and compensate for it by having slightly higher gain.

Comment: Thank you Andy for the reply. now I understand "input voltage range" parameter. I would change the OpAmp to LM324 or LM358. and what about I told about the Diode, I just want to nothing happen to the board if someone apply external voltage to the DAC connector, would you please explain how will diode work in the feedback loop ? it will not bother the operation ?

Comment: @EricMatevosian I don't think it would bother the operation but, I don't know much about your load circuit and the dynamics of the signal. An alternative is to use a reverse diode across the output to ground and, if necessary, use a fuse too. Putting the diode inside the feedback loop is what a [simple precision rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier) does. Maybe that will give you more help than limited room in comments. Simple PR --> https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Op-Amp_Precision_Rectifier.svg/250px-Op-Amp_Precision_Rectifier.svg.png

Comment: thank you a lot Andy <3